# Choice of View Engines in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, spark-view-engine, viewengine, razor-2, webforms-view-engine

I am developing a mobile application using ASP.Net MVC4.0, JQuery Mobile, HTML5. 
As I am new to ASP.Net MVC, I am not sure whether to use Razor(.cshtml) or webForm(.aspx) view engine.

Can anyone suggest which view engine I can use to develop a mobile application?
Performance wise which is better, the razor view-engine or webform view-engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a performance aspect.

However, I find the Razor syntax beautifully terse. The HTML is far more prominent with Razor, which is what you want when you're developing HTML views.

> In various MVC frameworks, view development encourages and requires
>   code written directly alongside markup. Because the ASPX view engine
>   was not designed with this goal in mind, the ASP.NET team decided to
>   build an entirely new view engine with a code-focused templating
>   approach. The result was a more intelligent parsing engine that is
>   able to very easily figure out where code stops and where markup
>   begins, without the developer needing to be very explicit.

There are even open-source view engines, that you might want to look at. For example, [Spark View Engine](http://sparkviewengine.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Razor is the preferred View Engine for MVC, ASPX View Engine is the legacy View Engine and this option is there for backward compatibility. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/470107/ASP-NET-MVC-4-Part-1-Introduction) you will find a great article who explain the differences between both.

Answer (score 0):

The ASPX engine is listed first.  A site we are working on scaling is using only Razor views.  Just having the ASPX engine before the razor engine was causing a huge amount to contention to occur when attempting to scale up the number requests.  Doing this:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
//Add Razor Engine
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine());
```

at startup made a huge difference given that each page access was no longer looking for existence of aspx, ascx files.  While it might not appear to affect performance on a single request, as you scale up and see contention and rising CPU percents, this is something one should check.

Comment: Did you put this answer on the wrong question? The question isn't about order of engines...